# How to filter array of map/key-pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the age above 21.

```
const people = [
     {0: {name: 'john', age: 30}},
     {1: {name: 'jay', age: 33}},
     {2: {name: 'cris', age: 18}}
];
```

I try the code below but it return empty result

```
const result = people.filter(person => person.age >= 21);
console.log(result);
```

0, 1, 2  are the index of array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does not initialize an array with the given indices, it creates separate objects with properties `0`, `1`, etc.

Declare the array like this:

```
const people = [
     {name: 'john', age: 30},
     {name: 'jay', age: 33},
     {name: 'cris', age: 18}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

> 0, 1, 2 are the index of array

I don't think they are, I believe they are the keys of the objects try this

```js
const people = [
     {0: {name: 'john', age: 30}},
     {1: {name: 'jay', age: 33}},
     {2: {name: 'cris', age: 18}}
];

const result = people.filter(person =>Object.values(person)[0].age >= 21);
console.log(result);
```

or declare your array like this and your code should work

```js
    const people = [
         {name: 'john', age: 30},
         {name: 'jay', age: 33},
         {name: 'cris', age: 18}
    ];
   const result = people.filter(person => person.age >= 21);
   console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works ONLY and ONLY if your keys `0, 1, 2..` are same as index.
If you change order of elements the solution will not work.

```
const people = [
     {0: {name: 'john', age: 30}},
     {1: {name: 'jay', age: 33}},
     {2: {name: 'cris', age: 18}}
];
people.filter((item, index) => item[index].age >= 21);
```